# Mirth Connect Administrator login error connecting to specified address (even though can access in browser)?

Tags: mirth

Installing Mirth Connect (3.10) on Ubuntu (18.04.4 LTS) based on the user guide here (https://www.nextgen.com/-/media/files/nextgen-connect/nextgen-connect-310-user-guide.pdf) and running into problem where can't log into the Mirth Connect Administrator view (pg.23 of the linked-to guide).

I see...
[image]
(where I'm using the default password "admin")

The `/usr/local/mirthconnect/logs/mirth.log` seems to show that the server is alive there

```
INFO  2020-12-06 20:52:19,670 [Main Server Thread] com.mirth.connect.server.Mirth: Mirth Connect 3.10.0 (Built on November 5, 2020) server successfully started.
INFO  2020-12-06 20:52:19,672 [Main Server Thread] com.mirth.connect.server.Mirth: This product was developed by NextGen Healthcare (https://www.nextgen.com) and its contributors (c)2005-2020.
INFO  2020-12-06 20:52:19,673 [Main Server Thread] com.mirth.connect.server.Mirth: Running OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM 11.0.9.1 on Linux (5.3.0-59-generic, amd64), derby, with charset UTF-8.
INFO  2020-12-06 20:52:19,673 [Main Server Thread] com.mirth.connect.server.Mirth: Web server running at http://172.18.4.124:8080/ and https://172.18.4.124:8443/
```

and I can connect to it on the web browser
[image]
and log into the Web Dashboard using user/password admin/admin, so not sure what the problem could be.

Anyone with more experience with this know what could be happening here?

Comment: Eventually gave up and just tried reinstalling by rerunning the installer. During that processes, saw that the person that originally installed the program set the password settings to be similar to our own internal standards for other things (eg. length > 10, etc). I set this back to the default settings as shown in the user manual and everything went fine after that. IDK if I should leave this question up, but I do still think it's helpful info (since to me its is not apparent that that setting would affect even the initial admin password being able to work).