# Mirth NextGen Connect desktop upper bar menu Server Manger links to wrong install of the Admin UI?

Tags: mirth

Having problem where the Mirth Connect Server Manager UI points to an earlier, non-working install version of the Admin interface.

Installed Mirth once and had to reinstall because the original install had set the password requirements to something that [the default admin account could not pass](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65177999/mirth-connect-administrator-login-error-connecting-to-specified-address-even-th#comment115227466_65177999). When I did this, the installer said that it detected that Mirth was already installed and asked if I wanted to re-install and I said yes. However, the Admin UI that the Mirth Connect Server Manager windows that remains in the upper menu bar of my desktop still appears to be using the old install with the password issue.

The Mirth Connect Server Manager icon in the upper menu bar takes me to wrong setup. Can't log in from the Admin UI that this bring up (told can't authenticate or connect (which was the problem I had with the earlier install)).
[image]
[image]

Need to use the Program from here
[image]
and make sure that I chose the right one, then I am able to use the default admin account to log in and proceed as normal.

Anyone know how to fix this (eg. somewhere in the underlying files where I can change this)? Anything else I should check that may be messed up due to this problem that I may not be noticing? I am on Ubuntu 18.04.4LTS MATE.

Answer (score 0):

In the installation folder\conf\mirth.properties file, change the HTTP and HTTPS ports to values different from the prior one. Get to your browser type localaddress:new_http port then click on the icon -launch Mirth Connect administrator. Clicking the saved shortcut will launch an admin launcher which will allow you to edit and save the functional instance.